# Integrate Game Center - cast value of type 'UIView' to SKView" error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center

So i am trying to add game center to my game but since that it is in spriteKit it wont work..

i've been looking and looking and evrything points out that it is only possible in a UIViewController..

buy all my buttons (like the button to go to HighScore(leaderboard) are in spriteKit...

so now i got this error

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x3755c3d8) to 'SKView' (0x36e116cc).
```

This is my GameViewController (The only file with a UIViewController) but it is used to just show me the TitleScene

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

var gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
var scene : TitleScene?
var gcEnabled = Bool()
var gcDefaultLeaderBoard = String()


func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

    let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(GameViewController, error) -> Void in
    if((GameViewController) != nil) {
        // 1 Show login if player is not logged in
        self.presentViewController(GameViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
        // 2 Player is already euthenticated & logged in, load game center
        self.gcEnabled = true

        // Get the default leaderboard ID
        localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardIdentifer: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                self.gcDefaultLeaderBoard = leaderboardIdentifer!
            }
        })


    } else {
        // 3 Game center is not enabled on the users device
        self.gcEnabled = false
        print("Local player could not be authenticated, disabling game center")
        print(error)
    }

}

}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let skView = self.view as! SKView

self.authenticateLocalPlayer()

scene = TitleScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
// Configure the view.

skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true

/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
scene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit
scene!.size = self.view.bounds.size



skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

and in my TitleScene i got this

```
class TitleScene: SKScene {

 if highScoreBtn.containsPoint(location) {
            let ScoreleaderboardID = "ScoreLeaderboardID"
            let sScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: ScoreleaderboardID)
            sScore.value = Int64(score)

            let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

            let gcVC: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
            gcVC.gameCenterDelegate = GameViewController()
            gcVC.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
            gcVC.leaderboardIdentifier = "LeaderboardID"
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(GameViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

            GKScore.reportScores([sScore], withCompletionHandler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Score submitted")

                }
            })


            print("highScoreBtn")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke nevermind i found it.

heres the solution to my problem.

**in GameViewController**

```
class GameViewController : UIViewController {

var scene : TitleScene?

// evrythong moved to TitleScene

}
```

**and like this in your TitleScene.**

```
class TitleScene :SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

  var gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    var gcEnabled = Bool()
    var gcDefaultLeaderBoard = String()

    func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
        let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(TitleScene, error) -> Void in
            if((TitleScene) != nil) {
                // 1 Show login if player is not logged in


// here it was original self.presentViewController(...)
// had to add self.view?.window?.rootController? to it

self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(TitleScene!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
                    // 2 Player is already euthenticated & logged in, load game center
                    self.gcEnabled = true



  // Get the default leaderboard ID
                    localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardIdentifer: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            self.gcDefaultLeaderBoard = leaderboardIdentifer!
                        }
                    })


            } else {
                // 3 Game center is not enabled on the users device
                self.gcEnabled = false
                print("Local player could not be authenticated, disabling game center")
                print(error)
            }

        }

    }

    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**didMoveToView function:**

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // in the didMoveToView you add the function

    self.authenticateLocalPlayer()

}
```

**and in the function to go to the leaderboard**

```
         if highScoreBtn.containsPoint(location) {
            let ScoreleaderboardID = "ScoreLeaderboardID"
            let sScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: ScoreleaderboardID)
            sScore.value = Int64(score)

            let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

            let gcVC: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
            gcVC.gameCenterDelegate = self
            gcVC.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
            gcVC.leaderboardIdentifier = "LeaderboardID"

//here i did the same as in with the other self.presentViewController

self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(gcVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            GKScore.reportScores([sScore], withCompletionHandler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Score submitted")

                }
            })


            print("highScoreBtn")
        }
```